# A macro “SCNxPTR” doesn't work on centos7

Tags: c++, macros, g++

SCNxPTR is defined in "inttypes.h", this file was truely included by my test.cpp, and SCNxPTR is defined as "x" in "inttypes.h",
but the compiler always complains that SCNxPTR is not declared.
gcc version is 7.3.0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(){
    std::cout << "scnxptr is: " << SCNxPTR << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

error message:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:5:35: error: ‘SCNxPTR’ was not declared in this scope
std::cout << "scnxptr is: " << SCNxPTR << std::endl;
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy-paste it, *as text*, into the question body instead.

Comment: Also note that in C++ the header file is really supposed to be `<cinttypes>`.

Comment: I think you’re not compiling with a recent enough standard.

Comment: thanks, you are right. @molbdnilo, it's because glibc, version before 2.17(include 2.17), SCNxPTR was defined depend the macro switch __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS, see details in Notes part https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer